# Pass template parameter to function which calls member functions

Tags: c++, templates

I want to pass a vector of type that is only known during compile time to a function which will pass it to other functions (to push elements depending on the type of vector).

How should i do it to ensure that the compiler does not throw the error:

test.cpp: In instantiation of 'void funcPushInt(std::vector) [with C = classB]':
test.cpp:28:20:   required from 'void checkType(std::vector) [with A = classB]'
test.cpp:53:16:   required from here
test.cpp:38:3: error: no matching function for call to 'std::vector::push_back(int&)'
   vec.push_back(i);
   ^

```
#include <typeinfo>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class classB
{
    private:
        int i;
    public:
        B()
        {
            i = 0;
        }
}

template <class A>
void checkType(vector<A>);
template <class C>
void funcPushInt(vector<C>);
template <class B>
void funcPushClassB(vector<B>);

template <class A>
void checkType(vector<A> vec)
{
  // check type of vec
  if(typeid(vec) == typeid(vector<int>)) 
    funcPushInt(vec);
  else if(typeid(vec) == typeid(vector<classB>))
    funcPushClassB(vec);
}

template <class C>
void funcPushInt(vector<C> vec)
{
  // push int
  int i = 1;
  vec.push_back(i);
}

template <class B>
void funcPushClassB(vector<B> vec)
{
  // error as it can't push float to vector<int>
  classB objB;
  vec.push_back(objB);
}

int main()
{
    // empty vec of classB type
  vector<classB> vec;
  checkType(vec);
}
```

Comment: I'm more concerned about all the template functions with no declared return types and by-value parameters upon which local changes mean nothing to the caller upon return

Comment: Classic XY problem. By the way, use `value_type`.

Comment: What are you really trying to do?

Comment: Basically:
1) check type of vector
2) depending on type, create object of that type and push it in

Comment: Create object how? Are you assuming it is default constructible?

Answer (score 2):

Your functions don't have a return type. Assuming that is an error of omission, you might as well have two functions.

```
template <class A>
void checkType(vector<A> vec)
{
    funcPushFloat(vec);
}

void checkType(vector<int> vec)
{
    funcPushInt(vec);
}
```

Comment: Thanks or the reply, but I want a single checkType function instead of using multiple functions. And yes, i left out the return types

Comment: Is there a technical reason why you want a single function?

Comment: Not really.. Just for convenience's sake and not having to repeat a bunch of code. I guess i'll have to do it that way then. Thanks R Sahu!